# Why do I get tkinter has no attribute 'Text' error in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I set up a large entry box using

```
    self.answer_entry = ttk.Entry(self, text='Answer')
    self.answer_entry.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=3, sticky='nesw')
    self.answer_entry.grid(ipady=50)
```

I haven't been able to find a way to align the text to the top of it so I wanted to play with Text instead of Entry.
When I try and change it to Text, I always get an error that says "Tkinter.ttk has no attribute 'Text'"

Entry works with this code:

```
def init_gui(self):
    """Builds GUI."""
    self.root.title('Verify')
    self.root.option_add('*tearOff', 'FALSE')

    self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew') # this starts the entire form

    self.menubar = tkinter.Menu(self.root)

    self.menu_file = tkinter.Menu(self.menubar)
    self.menu_file.add_command(label='About', command=self.on_help)
    self.menu_file.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.on_quit)

    self.menu_edit = tkinter.Menu(self.menubar)

    self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=self.menu_file, label='File')


    self.root.config(menu=self.menubar)

    self.workstation1_entry = ttk.Entry(self, width=30)
    self.workstation1_entry.grid(sticky='e', column=0, row=3)

    self.localid2_entry = ttk.Entry(self, width=30)
    self.localid2_entry.grid(sticky='e', column=1, row=3) 

    self.localid3_entry = ttk.Entry(self, width=30)
    self.localid3_entry.grid(sticky='e', column=2, row=3)

    self.calc_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Search', command=self.calculate) # button
    self.calc_button.grid(column=0, row=5, columnspan=3)

    self.answer_entry = ttk.Entry(self, text='Answer')
    self.answer_entry.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=3, sticky='nesw')
    self.answer_entry.grid(ipady=50)
```

How come I can't just change

```
 self.answer_entry = ttk.Entry(self, text='Answer')
```

to something like

```
 self.answer_entry = ttk.Text(self, text='Answer')
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why do I get tkinter has no attribute 'Text' error in Python Tkinter?

I hate to say it, but the answer is as simple as "you get that error because the ttk module does not have a Text widget". Why? Ask the people that created the module.

If you want a text widget, use the one in the tkinter module.

Comment: Maybe it is due to the fact that there is not much to style, and most users won't even notice. In macOS, I change the `highlightcolor` to "LightSteelBlue2" so it really blends with the rest of the interface and looks almost like a native widget.

Comment: ahhhhh lol That explains a lot.  I've thinking the modules were the same thing and wondering why all the examples I find don't work.  I'm stupid. haha

Comment: @Prox: they are two different modules with overlapping features.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Label, either in tkinter or ttk:

```
self.answer_entry = ttk.Label(self, text='Answer')
```

or

```
self.answer_entry = tkinter.Label(self, text='Answer')
```